# Parse Login Limit To Role

Tags: parse-platform

I have two mobile apps using the same parse app.

When I log a user in with parse is it possible to limit the login to a specific role?  I don't want users with role 'A' to be able to login to app 'B'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. Parse already has [entire sections of documentation dedicated to Roles](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#roles). Assuming you have already created a user and assigned a role, just add another piece of authentication logic to your login process for checking if the role is correct. When you are creating a new user from scratch, make sure to assign a role however you like.

Comment: I have the roles being set correctly.  Can I add it to the login request or do I have to take the logged in user and check against the role in the completion block?  And if it's in the completion block does that mean I have to make another query to get the role name to check against?

Comment: I believe this is something you will have to handle yourself either before or after logging in. You could perform a query on the Role class for the current user with the desired role. If the query returns nil, then don't log in. If the query returns the current user, then they are a match and you may proceed to log in.